# How to reproduce Internet Explorer Basic authentication with Javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I am actually facing an issue when it comes to login to our web apps using JavaScript. This is for Selenium test purpose
When manually browsing to the app, IE shoes the Auth popup, where user should provide *username* and *password*, to be access the web app.
I saw a lot of article explaining how to do so with XMLHttpRequest, but then we fall into the CORS issue.
The business restriction are, no access to the server, no privilege to change the IE settings. (I know it sounds weird, but this is for security matters).
What I want is, to do the same (login to the web app) via JavaScript (or any other programmatically way ).
For other browser (FF, Chrome), there is no problem. I can pass the credentials in the url and it is working.
The config:
* JDK 1.6
* Selenium 2.46.0
* IE 11

Comment: I just agreed with the team to add a type of error page, if user did not signed in yet. May be then the CORS issue will not hapen.
I will let you know about my outcomes :)

Comment: Hi Team,The solution was simple as that.
I added a public page in tomcat configuration (web.xml), to allow entering the domain. Then I applied XMLHttpRequest as described in many other post.
_var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); _
_xhr.open('GET', url, false, username, password);_
_xhr.send('');_

It works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Team,The solution was simple as that.

I added a public page in tomcat configuration (web.xml), to allow entering the domain. Then I applied XMLHttpRequest as described in many other post.
[answer]

*var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();*

*xhr.open('GET', url, false, username, password);*

*xhr.send('');*

It works perfect.